# Python echo the terminal outputs--no buffering

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a GUI.  The program enables VNC on a device.  So when I press GO button, it'll start with "Enabling VNC..."  It  takes a few seconds to enable.  Followed by a "sucCess"  message at upon completion.  I see this in the terminal.

I'm trying to do the same thing on the GUI.  The "enabling vnc" message doesn't even appear until the very end.  It appears together with the "success" message.  It's like it buffers all GUI output messages together then spits it all out in the end.

Here is what I have:

```
def actions():
# Enable VNC
if action_VNC.get():
    print("Enabling VNC...")
    msg_initVNC = "Enabling VNC..." + "\n"
    outText.insert(tk.END, msg_initVNC)

#DO STUFF HERE

    print('Success. VNC enabled.')
    print('########')
    msg_outVNC = 'Success.  VNC enabled.' + "\n" + '########' +"\n"
    outText.insert(tk.END, msg_outVNC)

window.mainloop()
```

The #DO STUFF HERE enables the VNC and it works.  It' takes about 3 -5 seconds to happen.  I'd like the program to output the print text to my GUI when it is supposed to and not wait until the end to output everything together.  It does this already on the terminal.   Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda buffered. GUIs work by "event driven" programming, which means that the visible window is not updated until a function is finished. This means you can't make functions in a GUI that take a long time to complete.

One way around this is to use the `threading` module.

```
from threading import Thread

def actions():
    # Enable VNC
    if action_VNC.get():
        print("Enabling VNC...")
        msg_initVNC = "Enabling VNC..." + "\n"
        outText.insert(tk.END, msg_initVNC)
        t = Thread(target=do_stuff, daemon=True)
        t.start() # start the worker function in the background
        
        root.bind("<<TaskDone>>", task_done) # listen for the task done event
        
def do_stuff():
    #DO STUFF HERE
    root.event_generate("<<TaskDone>>") # send the task done event

def task_done(*args):
    print('Success. VNC enabled.')
    print('########')
    msg_outVNC = 'Success.  VNC enabled.' + "\n" + '########' +"\n"
    outText.insert(tk.END, msg_outVNC)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Should the callback name `action_done` be `task_done`?

Answer (score 0):

I found `window.update_idletasks()` worked very well for me.  So my output code looks like this:

```
    outText.insert(tk.END, msg_seconds)
    window.update_idletasks()
```